# XSLT-select following items until particular tag

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

Consider I have this XML file:

```
<text>
  <w>John</w>
  <x>Smith</x>
  <z>Andy</z>
  <w>Goo</w>
  <w>Joseph</w>
  <y>Lee</y>
  <x>Kenny</x>
  <z>Maria</z>
  <y>Zoe</y>
  <z>Martin</z>
</text>
```

Now I wish to select elements between **1st** `<z>` and **2nd** `<z>`

So the output will be :

```
  <w>Goo</w>
  <w>Joseph</w>
  <y>Lee</y>
  <x>Kenny</x>
```

What I know is we can "copy-of" select the "following siblings" of "z[1]"
but I don't know how to stop it on "z[2]"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the intersection of the following two node-sets:

- All nodes after the first `z`
- All nodes before the second `z`

The intersection of these two sets will be all nodes between the first and second `z` elements. Use the following expression:

```
/*/z/following-sibling::*[
    count(.|/*/z[2]/preceding-sibling::*) =
    count(/*/z[2]/preceding-sibling::*)]
```

**Note**: This uses the Kayessian node-set intersection formula. In general, use the following to find the intersection of `$set1` and `$set2`:

```
$set1[count(.|$set2)=count($set2)]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use XPath:

```
text/*[preceding-sibling::z and following-sibling::z[2]]
```

e.g.:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="text/*[preceding-sibling::z and following-sibling::z[2]]"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```