# XSLT 1.0 grouping childs when followed by a certain node

Tags: xslt

Input xml:

```
<entry>
    <text>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <author>abc</author>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <author>abc</author>
    </text>
</entry>
```

I'm using XSLT 1.0.

I would like to select all `<p>` elements until the next `<author>` element and group them (together with the next `<author>` element) under a new `<div>` element. So expected output look like this:

```
<entry>
    <text>
      <div>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <author>abc</author>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <p>xyz</p>
        <author>abc</author>
      </div>
    </text>
</entry>
```

I tried this solution:

```
<xsl:template match="entry">
    <entry>
       <text>
         <div>
           <xsl:apply-templates select="child::node()[not(preceding-sibling::author)]"/>
         </div>
       </text>
    </entry>
</xsl:template>
```

which works fine for the first group of `<p>` + `<author>`, but not for the next group(s).

I would appreciate any help.

Comment: it's because the second row has indeed a preceding autor, so doens't match. Did you considered tu put </text><text> after every <autor>?

Comment: Maybe this post could help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8435716/xslt-select-following-items-until-particular-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may  group all elements before an author (`preceding-sibling:*` which are not author (`name() != 'author'`) and  have the current author as next following author 
(`generate-id( following-sibling::author[1]) = generate-id(current())`):

```
preceding-sibling::*[ name() != 'author' and
   generate-id( following-sibling::author[1]) = generate-id(current()) ]
```

Try something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="text">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="author" mode="adddiv"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="author" mode="adddiv" >
        <!-- preceding siblings not  author   -->
        <xsl:variable name="fs" select="preceding-sibling::*[ name() != 'author' and
                                             generate-id( following-sibling::author[1]
                                          ) = generate-id(current()) ]" />

        <div >
            <xsl:apply-templates select="$fs | ." />
        </div>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Which will generate the following output:

```
<entry>
  <text>
    <div>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <author>abc</author>
    </div>
    <div>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <p>xyz</p>
      <author>abc</author>
    </div>
  </text>
</entry>
```